# Why the result is not the same?

Tags: operator-precedence

I don't understand why the result of:

```
4 / 3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radio,3)
```

is different of:

```
(4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radio,3)) / 3
```

I use this in a program to calculate the sphere's volume.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: In the first case, 4/3 could be an integer division, resulting in 1

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov - The code is consistent with this being Java.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check for precedence of operator.

In your case precedence order is :

() > * > / (Note : this precedence is for C operators)

So for above operations result must be same for both cases.

Let's take

Case 1  :

`4 / 3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radio,3)

Here Math.PI = 3.14

Suppose Math.pow(radio , 3) = 10

In this scenario first multiplication will happen

result = 4*3.14*10 = 125.60000000000001

125.600/3 = 41.86666666666667`

Case 2 :

'(4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radio,3)) / 3'

Here first it will calculate () block then / operator

i.e `(4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radio,3))`

Here again result will be same as before

Answer (score 0):

First, lets insert some extra brackets ... for illustrative purposes:

This code:

```
    4 / 3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radio,3)
```

is equivalent to

```
    ((4 / 3) * Math.PI) * Math.pow(radio,3)
```

In words ... first we divide 4 by 3, then we multiply it by Pi, then we multiply by `radio` to the power of 3.

Now lets look at the first sub-expression `(4 / 3)`.  Since the operands are both integers, this is an integer division, and it produces an integer answer.  And that answer is `1`.  The answer you really need there is `1.33333...` but that isn't an integer.

How to fix it?  Changing either or both of the numbers to `double` literals will cause the division to be treated as a floating point (double) division, and that will you the best possible approximation to 4 thirds.

```
    4.0 / 3.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radio,3)
```